# Return distinct rows based on only one column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to return an n number of distinct rows. The distinct rows should be based on one column (SN) only.

I have the query below which is expected to return 4 rows where the serial number is greater than 2 and no rows with similar SN column values are returned.

Table

```
SN  letter value
 1   test   25
 1   bread  26
 3   alpha  43
 4   beta   23
 4   gamma  5
 5   omega  60
 6   omega  60
```

Expected Result

```
SN  letter value
 3   alpha  43
 4   beta   23
 5   omega  60
 6   omega 60
```

This is the query I have. This does not work correctly, it returns the duplicates because it filters disctinct values by all the columns combined instead of just the single column, SN.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, row_number() over(order by SN) rowRank 
FROM (SELECT distinct SN, letter, value from table where SN > 2 order by SN) a) 
WHERE rowRank BETWEEN 1 AND 4}"
```

Comment: Why there should be no row with SN = 6 in the result?

Comment: *where the serial number is greater than 3* in the question, `where SN > 2` in the code and SN=1 in the expected results. Edit your question and clarify what you want.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai and forpas I fixed the typos

Comment: With your sample data `distinct` isn't doing anything because you don't have any duplicate combinations of `SN, letter, value`. And `rowRank` was maybe intended to be `partition by SN order by <something else>`; at the moment it's indeterminate when there are two rows with the same SN. But you haven't said what that 'something else' is. For SN 4, what is the rule to get the row in your output; highest value? lowest 'letter'? other...? And what if there are still ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `DISTINCT` before trying to filter out your results. You can modify the `ORDER BY` clause of the `row_rank` analytic function if you need to modify which duplicate of a `SN` should be returned. Right now it is returning the first `LETTER` value alphabetically since that matches your example result.

### Query

```sql
WITH
    some_table (sn, letter, VALUE)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 'test', 25 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'bread', 26 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 'alpha', 43 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'beta', 23 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'gamma', 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 'omega', 60 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 'omega', 60 FROM DUAL)
  --Above is to set up the sample data. Use the query below with your real table
  SELECT sn, letter, VALUE
    FROM (SELECT sn,
                 letter,
                 VALUE,
                 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY letter)     AS row_rank
            FROM some_table
           WHERE sn > 2)
   WHERE row_rank = 1
ORDER BY sn
   FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY;
```

### Result

```
   SN    LETTER    VALUE
_____ _________ ________
    3 alpha           43
    4 beta            23
    5 omega           60
    6 omega           60
```

Comment: hi. why are you doing `...where row_rank = 1`?

Comment: that is added so that only 1 row of each `sn` appears in the results. The "row_rank" column is partitioned by `sn` so the counter resets with each `sn`

Comment: this looks hardcoded. I have a lot of rows. I cant input all the rows in the query. can you update the answer?

Comment: Nothing is hard coded other than `where sn > 2`. To use your data that you have stored in a table, remove the common table expression and change the table `some_table` to your real table that holds your data.

Comment: I was referring to this `(SELECT 1, 'test', 25 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 'bread', 26 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL...`. I need to remove this. when I do, what goes in there ?

Comment: That is the common table expression. I just added a comment to the query showing only the portion that you need to use.

Comment: Got that. shouldnt this be `PARTITION BY letter ORDER BY sn` instead of `PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY letter`  and what is the use of `PARTITION BY letter`? and how do I modify it so that the query fetches just the top 4 rows that match the conditions

Comment: I have modified the query to only return the first 4 rows. No, the partition by clause should not be changed. You can read about `PARTITION BY` with some examples here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions#query_partition_clause

Comment: I am using an older version of oracle so `fetch first n rows` does not work. I modified it to this which works but slow `WHERE row_rank = 1 and rownum <= 10
ORDER BY sn` would this produce the desired result in all cases and do you have a better/faster idea?

Comment: yes, that will work as well

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        t.* 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY value ) rn
        FROM 
        t
        WHERE sn > 2
    ) t1
 WHERE t1.rn = 1
 ORDER BY sn;
```

Comment: What is the point of ordering by a column that also appears in `PARTITION BY` in the same analytic function?

Comment: Order by sn inside partition by was not adding much significance, So I edited the result, thanks for highlighting

Comment: Hi. what us the reason for t1.rn = 1?

Comment: As per the requirement need to fetch only 1 record for EACH SN. To eliminate the extra records we are putting filter t1.rn = 1. By putting this filter only rows having row_number as 1 will be picked up.